# How to create a table with fixed width height and column width for each row and column?

Tags: tables

[image: What I'm trying to acheive]

I have made this much progress so far

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{-2cm}
    \Large
    SCOPE DOCUMENT REVISION HISTORY
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    % \begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}
    {\textwidth}
    % {|c|c|c}
    {|p{1cm}@{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{11ex}}|*{7}{C|}}
    % |@{}p{4cm}
    % \hline\xrowht[()]{0pt}
    \hline
    % \vspace{-1cm}
    % \rule{-10pt}{No.}
    % [-5ex]
    % \begin{center}
    % \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
    % \rule{0pt}{1cm} {No.} 
    No. & Comments & Action \\
    % \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\makeheight{1cm}No.} & Comments& Action 
    % \end{center}
    
    \hline
    % \vspace{1.75cm}
    % \begin{center}
      &  &   \\
    % \end{center}
    \hline
    % \vspace{1.75cm}
     &  &  \\
    \hline
    % \vspace{1.75cm}
     &  &  \\
    \hline
    % \vspace{1.75cm}
     &  &  \\
    \hline
    % \vspace{1.75cm}
     &  &  \\
    \hline
    % \vspace{1.75cm}
     &  &    \\
    \hline
    % \vspace{2cm}
    \end{tabularx}
    % \end{document}
\end{center}
% \begin{align}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\Large
\hspace{0.56cm}Supervisor signature:\\*
% \vspace{1cm
\vskip 0.2in
\end{document}
```

Can please someone tell me how I can turn it into the table I attached an image of? You would be doing me a huge favor, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Will you add any contents into this table or are you basically just interested in the gid lines and the column headers? Please turn your code fragment into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. How is the `C` type column defined?

Comment: Why do you define a total of 8 columns here? Your table only seems to need 3 columns.

Comment: @leandriis this is basically a comment box for people to write in with their pens, so yes it's supposed to be empty, I just want the the heading row to be narrow and center aligned like the image I have linked. And I'm sorry I have no idea what you mean by C type, I started learning latex two days ago.

Comment: @leandriis I don't know what you mean by the second comment, do you mean the 7 in '    {|p{1cm}@{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{11ex}}|*{7}{C|}}'? Again I'm sorry I'm just new to this and I have mostly been learning by experimenting and copy pasting latex.

Comment: @leandriis I made it MWE I think, is this okay?

Comment: `C` refers to the C in `*{7}{C|}`. This column type is not a standard one, you must have defined it somewhere or loaded a package that defines it. Otherwise you should get an error message complaining about an "Illegal pream-token". You declared a total of 8 columns: 1 column of the `p` type and 7 `C` columns.

Comment: @leandriis yes here it is \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the following results in an otuput closer to the expected one. The height of the rows can be adjusted by chaning the value inside of the []:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \vspace*{-2cm}
  \Large
  SCOPE DOCUMENT REVISION HISTORY
  \vspace{0.5cm}
    
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1cm}|*{2}{C|}}
    \hline
    No. & Comments & Action \\
    \hline
      &  &   \\[11ex]
    \hline
     &  &  \\[11ex]
    \hline
     &  &  \\[11ex]
    \hline
     &  &  \\[11ex]
    \hline
     &  &  \\[11ex]
    \hline
     &  &    \\[11ex]
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\Large
\noindent Supervisor signature:

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! You have no idea how much time I spent on this today haha. Thank you so much one again, I checked the mark, is there anything else I have to do?